# How to get Python Notebook (Jupyter/Colab) to reliably display emoji-variants of unicode characters?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, emoji, python-unicode

The Unicode U+FE0F invisible variation-selector character will often – & dare I say is *supposed-to* – cause many specific preceding characters to adopt an 'emoji' presentation, with standard emoji-width.

But, trying to get such emoji-display in the output of a Jupyter Notebook – specifically in Google Colab's version – the display is inconsistent, with *some* but not *all* chacters with emoji-variants never showing their emoji-version.

For example, a cell with code...

```py
copyright_plain = '©'  # U+00A9
copyright_emoji = '©️'  # U+00A9 U+FE0F
scissors_plain  = '✂'  # U+2702
scissors_var    = '✂︎'  # U+2702 U+FE0E
scissors_red    = '✂️'  # U+2702 U+FE0F
doubang_plain   = '‼'  # U+203C
doubang_var     = '‼︎'  # U+203C U+FE0E
doubang_emoji   = '‼️'  # U+203C U+FE0F
poo_emoji       = ''  # U+1F4A9

all = [copyright_plain, copyright_emoji, scissors_plain, scissors_black, scissors_red, 
       doubang_plain, doubang_var, doubang_emoji, poo_emoji]
print(f"list literal: {all}")
print(f"codes: {[('-'.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in chr)) for chr in all]}")
print(f"string: {''.join(all)}")
print("grid:")
for i in range(0, 11, 2):
  print(copyright_emoji*(i//2) + scissors_red*(10-i) + poo_emoji*(i//2))
```

…displays the following mixed & undesired output:

[image: inconsistent emoji glyphs as seen in notebook output cell]

Note that if I *paste* the cell output here to SO, even the `red_scissors` glyphs that appear properly, there, collapse back to plain variable-width black scissors here on SO:

```
list literal: ['©', '©️', '✂', '✂︎', '✂️', '‼', '‼︎', '‼️', '']
codes: ['0xa9', '0xa9-0xfe0f', '0x2702', '0x2702-0xfe0e', '0x2702-0xfe0f', '0x203c', '0x203c-0xfe0e', '0x203c-0xfe0f', '0x1f4a9']
string: ©©️✂✂︎✂️‼‼︎‼️
grid:
✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️
©️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️
©️©️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️✂️
©️©️©️✂️✂️✂️✂️
©️©️©️©️✂️✂️
©️©️©️©️©️
```

Ideally, the `©️` emoji-variant that's actually in the string would display as an emoji, making that 'grid' a perfect square, with each line exactly 10 emoji-widths across.

The in-notebook output is definitely retaining the necessary distinctions, without any visual impact, because if the same text is copied & pasted into a text view that works as desired – like say MacOS TextEdit – the desired display distinctions are seen:

[image: proper emoji-output of exact same text as above in MacOS TextEdit]

Is there any way to get Python notebook cells to fully-respect emoji-variants - at the very least in printed output cells, but also ideally in typed input (source code) cells, as well?